# Can I delete my EFI system partition?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

So I have Ubuntu on this drive and was wondering if I could remove one of these two partitions, heres a photo:

[image]

Also, something else: 
Why is this happening

[image]

Comment: If you were to delete your EFI partition you would be unable to boot into your operating system.  *It also appears you have Windows installed, as those screenshots are from Windows, not Ubuntu.*

Comment: Yeah I am running on windows, its on another drive

Comment: As for the reason your EFI partition is that large, I couldn't say, its about 100x the size it typically should be.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

For Your First Question:
if you want to not use The UEFI.

- you should change boot option in Bios to legacy mode. also disable secure boot if its enabled.
- in Linux systems probably you have to reconfigure grub or ellilo.

The EFI Partitions Usually are about 500MB in size !!! 10GB is a lot.

my advise is to shrink it out instead of removing it out.

Comment: You fail to address sufficient possible repercussions of messing with a system partition.

Comment: I cannot shrink it or do anything to it except delete, how can i assign a drive letter to that other partition as it wont let me

Comment: Just Consider if You Delete The Partition, You have to reinstall grub in order to boot Your Linux System Again. & trust me bro its not as easy as i told. it can be a kind of tricky.

why you want to assign a letter to it? i doubt you can access the content.

i just recommend partitioning tools in order to shrink the partition like Norton Ghost, Hiren or Gparted.

with these tools (Gparted) maybe you can shrink the partition.